# Filter is not working in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I would like to filter my data like assumes I have one model =>

- User

  - UserID
  - UserName
  - UserDescription

What I want is=>

- If i select like => `api/user/?userid=1` , It should return only
  userid  == 1 result.
- If I select like => `api/user/?username=test`,    It should return
  only username == test result.

What I have done?

I installed django-filter and add this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

to setting.py and I test like that but

**why I get all of my records?**  even URL is select only userid = 1  `api/user/?userid=1`

and

**If I test with the wrong URL parameter and I got all records even the wrong parameter.**

I do the exact same way with this => https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering

> Update

Here is View

```
class LeaveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Leave.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LeaveSerializer
```

Comment: can you show your views?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, Please check update, this is pretty sample viewset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the [**`filterset_fields`** - (doc)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#using-the-filterset-fields-shortcut) attribute

```
class LeaveViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Leave.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LeaveSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['user','other_fields']
```

Since you want to lookup a nested relation, you might specify the ***nested lookup*** as

```
filterset_fields = ['user__id','user__username']
```

and hence the URL will become, 
`api/user/?user__id=1`

Comment: It should work as is :) Check the URL structure anyway

Comment: Ok but let say field name in the model is "EmpNo" but why I can't set like filterset_fields = ['empno'] ? its case sensitive?

Comment: Yeah... It's case sensitive. You should use **`filterset_fields = ['EmpNo']`**

Comment: Thank you, filterset_fields is working I think it is updated, rest of the stackoverflow answers using filter_fields which did not work.